# ie8 Expected Identifier error - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

My app is running in almost all browsers but when I use ie8 Expected Identifier happened.

```
 $scope.delete = function (index) {

        $scope.recipelists.splice(index, 1);

        localStorage.setItem('markedRecipes', JSON.stringify($scope.recipelists))

        if ($scope.recipelists == 0) {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
}
```

this is where ie8's console direct me when the error shows.

I don't know what's wrong with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do IE8 supports local storage?

Comment: This might answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage

Comment: @qamar: Either way, that would throw a reference error, not a *syntax* error.

Comment: Check if any of these is a possibility,
 



   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number

Comment: is `.splice` is causing a problem?

Comment: delete is a keyword in javascript so it may cause problem also as pankaj said .splice can also cause problem. not sure will need to check.

Comment: Thanks! I got it with Felix's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IE8 doesn't support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) [reserved words](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1) as literal object properties. Use

```
$scope['delete']
```

instead.

Comment: If you have a decent syntax highlighter installed you can normally catch these errors. Somehow $scope.case when past me.. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding IE8 give storage to only valid domains. Try placing your example in some Web-server it should resolve the issue.

I faced the same issue when I tested it as an individual file but when i placed it in a server(Tomcat in my case) it just worked fine.

Source:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776794/1632286

Comment: The app is in our IIS.