# IE8 localstorage storage event

Tags: local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does IE8 out-of-the-box have support for ‘localStorage’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage)

I am using in my app `localStorage` and I need and event listener to when something updates in `localStorage`. Everything works fine on most browsers (I can get the key, new value from the event) but on `IE8` I can't get it working.

Comment: Is your browser in Compatibility mode for IE7?

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as a duplicate, as the original doesn't answer the question.

I too would like to know if there's a workaround - AFAICT, the localstorage change event doesn't behave according to the spec in IE8 (surprise, surprise).