# HTML5 localStorage getItem issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

I have the following code for `localStorage`:

```
function supports_html5_storage() 
{
    try { 
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null; 
    } 
    catch (e) {
        return false; 
    } 
}

function setFormFieldValues()
{
    if (supports_html5_storage()) {
        var retrievedUserDataObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserDataObj'));
        if (retrievedUserDataObj) {
            ...
        }       
    }
}
```

Now this works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8, I get the following error:

> Unable to get value of the property 'getItem': object is null or undefined

Comment: This has been answered in some other posts. Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage.

Comment: @Aiias I don't see an answer in that post.

Comment: I don't think that this is a dup. In the other question it is stated that `window.localStorage` is undefined. In here OP says that a property of `window.localStorage` is missing.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it was due to window.localStorage returning null due to the DOCTYPE not being defined. `getItem` should be supported by IE8. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197039(v=vs.85).aspx) on `getItem`.

Comment: I have my doctype defined as <!doctype html> ...Still not working in IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. A little more direct if you're already using `try/catch`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script:

```js
function supports_html5_storage() {
    try {
        window.localStorage.setItem( 'checkLocalStorage', true );
        window.localStorage.removeItem( 'checkLocalStorage' );
        return true;
    } catch ( error ) {
        return false;
    };
};

document.getElementById( 'result' ).textContent = 
    'localstorage: ' + supports_html5_storage();
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```