# How to activate menu tab after refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I activate a menu tab after refreshing?

Here are my code

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
  .menu{width: 600px; height: 25; font-size: 18px;}
  .menu li{list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 4px; padding: 5px;}
  .menu li:hover, .menu li.active {
        background-color: #f90;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href='#'>One</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Four</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());

  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  )


  //Add the clicked button class
  $(this).addClass('active');
}

//Attach events to menu
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
  }  
)

</script>
```

Can anyone tell me How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I removed the `java` as obviously this has nothing to do with it, added javascript, jquery...

Comment: properly elaborate what exactly want to do

Comment: Sounds to me like you're referring to refreshing the page. `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` or `$.cookie` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Johan said, store your last active tab in a `localStorage` or `cookie`. Since there is no noticeable difference in performance between the two. I suggest you use `localStorage` because it's much easier to use. Like this:

```
function make_button_active(tab) {
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings = tab.siblings();

  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  })

  //Add the clicked button class
  tab.addClass('active');
}

//Attach events to menu
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(localStorage){ 
      var ind = localStorage['tab']       
      make_button_active($('.menu li').eq(ind));
  }

  $(".menu li").click(function () {
      if(localStorage){ 
          localStorage['tab'] = $(this).index();
      }
      make_button_active($(this));
   });

});
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/kCxnX/).

Comment: thank you for your answer Mark S, it working in Mozilla, but it not working in internet explorer,how to fix it

Comment: I see, are you using ie8? then check this post [Does IE8 out-of-the-box have support for 'localStorage'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage). If it's still not working for you, then I think you should switch to `cookie`. There is a plugin you can use to help you set and retrieve cookies easily - [**jQuery.cookie**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). But I also wanted to share how you can do it with just javascript. See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/kCxnX/3/)