# How can I show recent searches done through a textbox using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve is that when I focus on the search bar, it should show me a list of recent searches done during this session and I should be able to select one of them and it should appear on the textbook.

Any help appreciated. If possible I woul like to store these recent searches data to browser cache so that whenever I reach this website it should show me the list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use HTML5 localstorage or session or cookie to store search values. and retrive them as recent search when you want.

Comment: Okay. But this page needs compatibility with IE8 and I guess HTML5 features don't work for this version of IE. How to achieve this on IE?

Comment: Then use session variable or cookies.

Comment: [`Your facts`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage) are wrong. [`IE8 supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) local storage

Comment: If each user has their own login update a database with an array of their search history each time they search. then when they return reload the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will be using a web based language like html or JavaScript, a good start would be to store each search in an array.

using javascript along with the jQuery library you can easily add items to an array each time a user clicks a button.

JavaScript:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push($('#yourTextBox').val());
```

Then you could use jquery's $.each function to display each item in a DOM element.

See the sample below: (I used HTML and javascript with jquery 1.11)

http://jsfiddle.net/1ncf0b6f/3/

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR I've written a library to handle this + it's edge cases, see https://github.com/JonasBa/recent-searches#readme for usage.**

You should store the recent searchees in LocalStorage and retrieve them, then decide on your implementation on how you want to render them. This obviously has some edge cases that you need to consider, which is why I wrote a library to do exactly this, see below examples

**Examples**
Expiration:
Consider that someone searches for a query `iPhone`, but has looked for a query `repairing iPhone` 1 month ago, that repairing iPhone query is likely obsolete.

**Ranking of recent searches**
Same goes for ranking when doing prefix search, if a user has made a query "apple television" 3h ago and a query "television cables" 8h ago, and they now search for "television", you want to probably implement a ranking system for the two.

*Safely handling storage*
Just writing to LocalStorage will result in a massive JSON that you'll need to parse every time, thus gradually slowing down your application until you hit the limit and loose this functionality.

I've built a recent-searches library which helps you tackle all that. You can use it via npm and find it [here](https://github.com/JonasBa/recent-searches#readme). It will help you with all of the above issues and allow you to build recent-searches really quickly!