# Local Storage does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer

I am working on a project in which I need to display new data whenever data in database changes, so I am using the local storage concept. Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer it's not working. I understand that it's a problem with local storage in IE. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this using ASP.net?

```js
if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {

    //use localStorage object to store data
    try {
        var webmethod = top.GetBaseUrl() + '/GetNewlyGeneratedEvents.aspx';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: webmethod,
            success: function (msg) {
                var htmlCnt = $.parseHTML(msg);
                var text = $(htmlCnt).find('#divNewEvents').html();
                if (localStorage.length > 0) {
                    localStorage.clear();
                }
                localStorage.setItem('NewEvents', text);

                UpdateNewEventContent(text);

               
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("error in bringing newEventData");
            },
            async: true
        });

    } catch (e) {
        if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
            alert('Quota exceeded!');
        }
    }


} else {
    alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is *never* enough detail. What do you see? What have you tried to diagnose the issue? (And what does this have to do with C#? Additionally, please put more effort into formatting your code in future - most of it was indented miles to the right for no reason.)

Comment: `localStorage` in IEs works fine, except you can't use it when running the code locally.

Comment: thanks for replay @JonSkeet . i mean whenever new data in database i can able to display that data in browers like chrome and firefox but but in IE its neither giving any error like "Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage" nor displaying anydata

Comment: Are you sure `GetBaseUrl` and `UpdateNewEventContent` are working as expected? Also if you removed the `try..catch`, you might see some error(s), currently you're checking only if a particular error occurs.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: yap. everything is working fine except the case with IE@Teemu. GetBaseUrl and UpdateNewEventContent are my own functions these r working fine

Comment: I am using IE8@GoBusto

Comment: Maybe in other browsers, but in IE8? It needs also jQuery 1.X version to work. Btw, how an automatically created error object could be equal to any other object? I'm afraid the `if` will never be passed within `catch`. Also, please edit your question to contain all the information you've written to comments.

Comment: If you're using IE8, then perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage