# oauth token sharing multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

My applications structure is like below -

```
https://democompany.com/
https://democompany.com/app1
https://democompany.com/api
```

User logs in at main website url https://democompany.com/logon.aspx which is a asp.net webforms application.

app1 application is an angularjs application which uses /api app. api is webapi2 application which uses oauth token for authentication. I would like have the user login only once at democompany.com/logon.aspx and pass the  oauth token to angularjs application.

Is there a recommended way to pass oauth token from one application to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your applications use one subdomain, you can use client side  window.localStorage for that purposes.

```
// to set token in storage    
window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
// to get token from storage
access_token = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
```

So you will have access to that storage from every page with some javascript code. For example with combination of angular + web.api you can setup token for all your requests in $http service:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token;
```

Also you can use `interceptor` to setup token if you want to have more control of your code.

Comment: Does window.localStorage work in ie8  and ie9 browsers? Thank you for answering !

Comment: I never used it for ie8, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage) answer it does.
Also you can see table of compatibility [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage says that unless you are using IE6/IE7 or Opera Mini, it should work everywhere including mobile.

Comment: there is a library  for cross domain local storage with angular
https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage

Comment: @AlainIb - Thank you, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're describing is the definition of Cookies.