# there are two html pages. I want the data status of first pages to saved when I reverting from next page to first page

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on back button of next page the check box value should not be reset.

It should be same as I checked or unchecked. The code from the first and next page is below.

### First Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="code" value="ECE">ECE<br>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="code" value="CSE">CSE<br>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="code" value="ISE">ISE<br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" onclick="dropFunction()" value="save">
                <br><br>

                <script>
                    function dropFunction() {
                        var branch = document.getElementsByName("code");
                        var out = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
                            if (branch[i].checked == true) {
                                out = out + branch[i].value + " ";
                                window.location.href="next.html";
                            }
                        }
                    }
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Next Page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to </title>
    </head>
    <body color="yellow" text="blue">
        <h1>welcome to page</h1>
        <h2>here we go </h2>

        <p> hello everybody<br></p>
        </body>
        <image src="D:\images.jpg" width="300" height="200"><br>
        <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
        <script>
        function goBack() {
            window.location.href="first.html";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since HTTP is stateless, you need to store those changes in session, or a cookie, or browser's local storage or a database.

Comment: How to store that. Any sample code do u know.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6d5Tn4z5ilpi2NpgDe9?p=preview). First add ids to your checkboxes:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="code" value="ECE" id='1'>ECE<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="code" value="CSE" id='2'>CSE<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="code" value="ISE" id='3'>ISE<br>
    <input id="spy"  style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Then change your dropFunction:

```
function dropFunction() {
    var branch = document.getElementsByName("code");
    var out = "";

    localStorage.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++)
        if (branch[i].checked == true)     
            localStorage.setItem(branch[i].id, true);

    for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
        if (branch[i].checked == true) {
            out = out + branch[i].value + " ";
            window.location.href="next.html";    
        }
    }

}
```

And add some new javascript code to first.html:

```
window.onload = function() {                  
     var spy = document.getElementById("spy");

     if(spy.value=='visited')
         for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
             if(localStorage.getItem(i))
                document.getElementById(i).checked=true;
     spy.value = 'visited';                            
}
```

Comment: Wheen I clicked on save in first page by selecting on of the check box, its showing error in page and not moving to next page

Comment: Sorry, I make little mistake - one unnecessary token - "{", please check this: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6d5Tn4z5ilpi2NpgDe9?p=preview)

Comment: I am glad, better late than never.

Comment: If I close the window and open the file again that checked box should be reset..Is it possible ??

Comment: Yes, check [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6d5Tn4z5ilpi2NpgDe9?p=preview) again, I added only one new row: `if(document.referrer.indexOf('next.html')!=-1)` inside `window.onload` function. Try to refresh page after returning from next.html page.

Comment: Hi.. Its not working on google chrome and explorer, in chrome after going back from the next page to first page checkboxes are getting reset. and in explorer its showing error

Comment: I added hidden input "spy" and changed `window.location.href="first.html";` at next .html to `window.history.back();` and `window.onload`. Check [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6d5Tn4z5ilpi2NpgDe9?p=preview) again.

Comment: What is version of IE are you using? And what is error message? I tried my example on IE11, it worked correct at plunker.

Comment: error is localStorage is null or not an object in first.html line numbr 20

Comment: I think, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage) is what you need.