# Is there a way to find the maximum size of localStorage for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension. I know that Chrome currently sets the limit of 5MB on the maximum allowed size of `localStorage`. But I'm curious if there's any way to get this from the Chrome itself, anything like a JS constant/global variable?

PS. I just hate to hard-code this value in case they change it in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391575/how-to-find-the-size-of-localstorage

Comment: @charlietfl: I'm sorry, but how does that answer my question?

Comment: follow the links, there are examples of how to load to fail point, and explanations that there is no sort of `getSize()` method

Comment: @charlietfl: That is a very cumbersome method of finding it out, plus it may take a lot of time and resource usage on the client system.

Comment: don't shoot the messenger, just pointing out resources for you

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks. I found that page too. I was just hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: actually a bit surprised there isn't a clean simple API approach myself

Comment: simply declare unlimitedStorage

Comment: @ZigMandel: Can I do this for an extension. Any code examples?

Comment: first google it. its right there.

Answer (score 0):

> We assume that one character equals one byte, but this is not a safe assumption. Strings in JavaScript are UTF-16, so each character requires two bytes of memory. This means that while many browsers have a 5 MB limit, you can only store 2.5 M characters.

It is quite difficult to predict how much is left for the domain, even if it is set to 5 MB.

After reading through about HTML5 Storage. It is quite possible to look for unlimited storage option.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#unlimited

In this documentation they are suggesting manifest as:

```
 "storage": {
    "managed_schema": "schema.json"
  },
```

I have not tested myself but it is worth to give it a try. If it works then please let me know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Updated 2021:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-local

Use `chrome.storage.local.QUOTA_BYTES`.