# HTML5 Localstorage space left

Tags: local-storage

How can I calculate how much space is left for storing data?

I want to warn the user that disk space(localstorage space) is almost full and they must remove some items.

It would be cool to be able to make an [pie chart](http://www.mactip.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/mac_jdiskreport_pie_chart.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no programatic API for this (although IE has support for telling you how much space is left), and max sizes differ among browsers (see [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)). If I were storing a *lot* of data, I'd probably skip LocalStorage and use IndexedDB or WebSQL (which is a dead spec, but still works well in a lot of cases). I tend to only use LocalStorage for "known" data sets. Ie, preferences, caches, etc. I compare this to "unknown datasets" (not a great name) for things like user notes, etc, where I'd push IDB/WebSQL instead.

You *could* safely assume 5 megs or so and get the size ([How to find the size of localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391575/how-to-find-the-size-of-localstorage)).

As an FYI, there *is* work being done to make this better so it won't be so vague in the future.