# Ionic Android app stops storing after cache reaches 10.3MB

Tags: android, caching, ionic-framework, appdata

I built an Ionic app for a client that enables him to take pictures and store them with LocalStorageService. He reports that once the app's cache reaches 10.3 MB, pictures that he take are no longer stored.

Once deleting the application's cache, he wipes all the pictures he took and can resume adding new pictures.

I try this on my device and cannot replicate the issue. I am using a Samsung S6 with Marshmallow while the client is using a cheap tablet running Lollipop. Am I missing something here?

Comment: By LocalStorage, do you mean browser local storage? :O

Comment: I think you're on to something. I was under the impression that localstorage was limitless, like saving to disk. Is it truly just saving to browser cache? If so, what are the limitations?

Comment: nope! Theres a limit. Normally 5mb for firefox and 10 for chrome, per origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalStorage` is not meant to store files of size in MBs or files at all (certainly not images). Most of the time, Chrome provides 10MB of space and Firefox provides 5MB (based on this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage)). However, it is not guaranteed as it's not specified in their documentation. They can be anywhere from 2 MB - unlimited.

> I am using a Samsung S6 with Marshmallow while the client is using a cheap tablet running Lollipop. Am I missing something here?

- Like I stated above, there could be difference in the capacity of `LocalStorage` of the two devices. ([How to check LocalStorage size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391575/how-to-find-the-size-of-localstorage))

You can use [File Transfer Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) and store the image files on your device. Once you do that, you can then use `LocalStorage` or [SQLite](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) to keep track of the path of the image the user downloaded.