# How to Check that how much offline storage has been Used

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline, offline-caching, offline-browsing

I am using offline storage and want to clear it when storage memory is full. All I want is to know that how to get used storage. I am using the following code to clear offline storage:

```
  localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391575/how-to-find-the-size-of-localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `localStorage.length` to get the count of elements in the storage. But it is unlikely that it will directly give away the size (in bytes) of how much storage is used - unless you are storing monotonic data that lets you predict the size based on the count of keys.

But you do get a `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` exception when setting values if you do exceed the available limit. So, just wrap your code in a `try..catch` and if you do get `error.type` as `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR`, then you could clear the space.

You could also iterate over all items in the storage to get its full size. But I would not do that given that it might take a bit of time as the storage increases. In case you are interested, something like this would work:

```
var size = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
  size += localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).length;
}

console.log("Size: " + size);
```

Ref: [What happens when localStorage is full?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191200/5894241)

PS: I tried to get the size by iterating over the localStorage keys, and adding the size, but the browser tab crashed. So I'd say relying on the `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` is better.

### UPDATE

You could also get a rough estimate of size using `JSON.stringify(localStorage).length`. Which seems faster than iterating over the keys, and doesn't crash the browser. But keep in mind that it contains additional JSON characters (such as `{`,`}`,`,` and `"`) as browser would use them to wrap the keys and values. So the size would be slightly higher than the actual value.