# How to set session using Nuxt-Auth?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am trying to use [**Nuxt/auth**](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/), but run into problem with session saving in `localStorage`.

Login.vue

```
methods: {
sendLoginLink() {
  this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
    data: {
      username: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "testpassword"
    }
  }).then((date) => {
    console.log("data", date)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error("err", err)
  })
}
```

Nuxt.config.js

```
 auth: {
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: '/dashboard', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' }
    },
    tokenType: ''
  }
}

axios: {
baseURL: 'http://localhost:1234'
},

  modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'@nuxtjs/auth-next', 
]
```

When the user logs in, the function **sendLoginLink** is called and throw error in console:

[image]

Which means that the auth-token is so large that it cannot be stored in `localStorage`, but all other things related to this function are saved in `localStorage`.  For example:

[image]

I googled a lot but didn't find a good solution to the problem. For example, I tried to clear all `localStorage` memory before running **sendLoginLink()** function but the result is the same. Different browsers have the same problem

Comment: PS: cookies tend to be more secure than `localStorage`. Meanwhile, the max limit for cookie is  4KB, while this is 5MB for `localStorage`. IMO, the issue here is more of **why** you do have the size limit reached? Are you sure the backend is sending you the correct thing (a small simple string is enough for the token). Maybe try to inspect your storage before and after to see how it may reach the allowed max: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720835/8816585