# How to show the remaining space of the localStorage?

Tags: local-storage, space

I'm creating a webapp which uses the localStorage.

I would like to show something like: X % is used over Y Megabytes

How to calculate that?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

IE has a proprietary propery "window.localStorage.remainingSpace" which returns the remaining space in bytes.  Unfortunately can't find similar functionality in any of the other browsers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197016(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will help you out [Calculating usage of localStorage space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027142/calculating-usage-of-localstorage-space)

There is no way to query to browser for that exact information

Comment: What they are doing in that answer is constantly writing to LocalStorage until it fills up, that way they know how much space there is