# Estimating the size of a 10,000 character string stored in localStorage (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am building an application that allows for a finite amount of local storage. I am snagging the text from a web-page and storing it in local storage.  I am trying to figure out how many of these I will be able to store (roughly) before hitting my max of 5mb.

Any idea how big a 10,000 character string would be stored in localStorage?

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027142/calculating-usage-of-localstorage-space

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-takes-one-unicode-character.

But if one character takes up 1 byte as Yahoo Answers says, you can store 5,243,000 characters until you get to 5MB, and 10,000 characters would take up 0.009536743MB. So I think you're pretty safe.

Yahoo Answers also says that a unicode character takes up 2 bytes.

Comment: great info, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just calculate with 20,000 bytes for 10,000 characters. Should be a safe bet for UFT-8 and match what is needed for UTF-16

Comment: so if your estimations are correct, it seems that I could store around 262 of these bad boys before hitting 5mb.