# In angularjs how do you catch an error for ngStorage when localStorage is full?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I am saving several items to `localStorage` using `ngStorage` in AngularJS, but if the user's `localStorage` is full how can I catch that error and allow the JavaScript to keep running?

```
try {  
    $scope.$storage.gridObject = $scope.gridConfig.data;  
    $scope.$storage.dataStored=true; 
}  
catch(err) {  
    //failed to save to local storage,  try clearing localStorage for IAP and throw error  
    $scope.$storage.dataStored=false;  
    $scope.$storage.$reset({    
        dataStored: false,
        gridObject: {}  
    })  
    console.log('error occured message');  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not specific to AngularJS, you should be able to get some detailed information for your `localStorage` with the following.

```
var allocated = 5; // default 5MB allocation
var total = 0;
for(var x in localStorage) {  
    var amount = (localStorage[x].length * 2) / 1024 / 1024;  
    total += amount;  
}
var remaining = allocated - total;
console.log( 'Used: ' + total + ' MB');
console.log( 'Remaining: ' + remaining + ' MB');
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/p83rfp21/) - demo

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027249/1464112) as well for an exception driven approach. The referenced answer will share how you can force an exception you can likely catch for. The code above may allow you to perform/bypass certain logic if you are running low.