# HTML5 localStorage useful Functions // JavaScript, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, local-storage

How to: *

- Check if `localStorage` is supported
- Check if `localStorage` has an Item
- Get the amount of space left in `localStorage`
- Get the maximum amount of space in `localStorage`
- Get the used space in `localStorage`
- Get a Backup of `localStorage`
- Apply a Backup to `localStorage`
- Dump all information of `localStorage` in the console

**check the answers below*

---

FAQ:

- [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/4339170) How to store Objects in `localStorage`
- [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357553/4339170) How to store an Array in `localStorage`
- [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19183180/4339170) How to save an Image in `localStorage`
- [[link]](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-overview-of-the-web-storage-api/) `localStorage` Tutorial (also covers *storage events* and *things to remember*)

---

Related:

- [[link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) General Information about Web Storage
- [[link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) `sessionStorage` data stored gets cleared when the page session ends
- [[link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) `indexedDB` a low-level API for client-side storage of structured data

Comment: Hey, while we normally condone and even encourage writing long, detailed Q&A, this post feels more like a tag wiki. It isn't formatted in the form of a question and an answer, and doesn't solve or elaborate on any particular problem.

Comment: As you can see I invested quite some time, answering these 8 questions and problems. While they could be posted as an individual Q&A each, I feel like they can be answered together in a clean topic, used as references in later questions, search and general help. If prefered I can post this as 5 questions. However if this is too much out of the Box, I'll promise to never abuse StackOverflow again with my answers.

Comment: @CodeiSir I greatly appreciate your code provided here. Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### My suite of functions for `localStorage` in JavaScript and TypeScript

- `isSupported`
- `hasItem(key)`
- `getSpaceLeft()`
- `getMaximumSace()`
- `getUsedSpace()`
- `getItemUsedSpace()`
- `getBackup()`
- `applyBackup(backup, fClear, fOverwriteExisting)`
- `consoleInfo(fShowMaximumSize)`

The complete code as `LocalStorage`-Module on GitHubGist: [JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/CodeiSir/9a01625edaf25e11a4e5) and [TypeScript](https://gist.github.com/CodeiSir/1fb8bd9154dfde7eb0c7)
Live example: on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rqtd7pg/1/)

Check if localStorage is supported - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20%20*%20Flag%20set%20true%20if%20the%20Browser%20supports%20localStorage%0A%20%20*%2F%0Aconst%20isSupported%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09try%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20itemBackup%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(%22%22)%0A%09%09localStorage.removeItem(%22%22)%3B%0A%09%09localStorage.setItem(%22%22%2C%20itemBackup)%3B%0A%09%09if%20(itemBackup%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20localStorage.removeItem(%22%22)%0A%09%09else%20localStorage.setItem(%22%22%2C%20itemBackup)%0A%09%09return%20true%3B%0A%09%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20false%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)())

```
/**
  * Flag set true if the Browser supports localStorage, without affecting it
  */
var localStorage_isSupported = (function () {
    try {
        var itemBackup = localStorage.getItem("");
        localStorage.removeItem("");
        localStorage.setItem("", itemBackup);
        if (itemBackup === null)
            localStorage.removeItem("");
        else
            localStorage.setItem("", itemBackup);
        return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})();
```

Check if localStorage has an Item - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20*%20Check%20if%20localStorage%20has%20an%20Item%20%2F%20exists%20with%20the%20give%20key%0A%20*%20%40param%20key%20the%20key%20of%20the%20Item%0A%20*%2F%0Afunction%20localStorage_hasItem(key%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20localStorage.getItem(key)%20!%3D%3D%20null%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * Check if localStorage has an Item / exists with the give key
 * @param key the key of the Item
 */
function localStorage_hasItem(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key) !== null;
}
```

Get the amount of space left in localStorage - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20*%20This%20will%20return%20the%20left%20space%20in%20localStorage%20without%20affecting%20it's%20content%0A%20*%20Might%20be%20slow%20!!!%0A%20*%2F%0Afunction%20getRemainingSpace()%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%09let%20itemBackup%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(%22%22)%0A%09let%20increase%20%3D%20true%0A%09let%20data%20%3D%20%221%22%0A%09let%20totalData%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09let%20trytotalData%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09while%20(true)%20%7B%0A%09%09try%20%7B%0A%09%09%09trytotalData%20%3D%20totalData%20%2B%20data%0A%09%09%09localStorage.setItem(%22%22%2C%20trytotalData)%3B%0A%09%09%09totalData%20%3D%20trytotalData%3B%0A%09%09%09if%20(increase)%20data%20%2B%3D%20data%0A%09%09%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20(data.length%20%3C%202)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09break%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09increase%20%3D%20false%0A%09%09%09data%20%3D%20data.substr(data.length%20%2F%202)%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09if%20(itemBackup%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20localStorage.removeItem(%22%22)%0A%09else%20localStorage.setItem(%22%22%2C%20itemBackup)%0A%0A%09return%20totalData.length%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * This will return the left space in localStorage without affecting it's content
 * Might be slow !!!
 */
function localStorage_getRemainingSpace() {
    var itemBackup = localStorage.getItem("");
    var increase = true;
    var data = "1";
    var totalData = "";
    var trytotalData = "";
    while (true) {
        try {
            trytotalData = totalData + data;
            localStorage.setItem("", trytotalData);
            totalData = trytotalData;
            if (increase)
                data += data;
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (data.length < 2) {
                break;
            }
            increase = false;
            data = data.substr(data.length / 2);
        }
    }
    if (itemBackup === null)
        localStorage.removeItem("");
    else
        localStorage.setItem("", itemBackup);
    return totalData.length;
}
```

Get the maximum amount of space in localStorage - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20%20%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20This%20function%20returns%20the%20maximum%20size%20of%20localStorage%20without%20affecting%20it's%20content%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Might%20be%20slow%20!!!%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20getMaximumSpace()%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20backup%20%3D%20localStorage_getBackup()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20localStorage.clear()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20max%20%3D%20localStorage_getRemainingSpace()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20localStorage_applyBackup(backup)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20max%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

```
/**
 * This function returns the maximum size of localStorage without affecting it's content
 * Might be slow !!!
 */
function localStorage_getMaximumSize() {
    var backup = localStorage_getBackup();
    localStorage.clear()
    var max = localStorage_getRemainingSpace();
    localStorage_applyBackup(backup);
    return max;
}
```

Get the used space in localStorage - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%09*%20This%20will%20return%20the%20currently%20used%20size%20of%20localStorage%0A%09*%2F%0Aexport%20function%20getUsedSpace()%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%09let%20sum%20%3D%200%0A%0A%09for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20localStorage.length%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%0A%09%09var%20key%20%3D%20localStorage.key(i)%0A%09%09let%20value%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(key)%0A%09%09sum%20%2B%3D%20key.length%20%2B%20value.length%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09return%20sum%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * This will return the currently used size of localStorage
 */
function localStorage_getUsedSize() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i)
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        sum += key.length + value.length;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Get the space used my an Item [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20*%20This%20will%20return%20the%20currently%20used%20size%20of%20a%20given%20Item%2C%20returns%20NaN%20if%20key%20is%20not%20found%0A%20*%20%40param%20key%0A%20*%2F%0Afunction%20getItemUsedSpace(key%3A%20string)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%09let%20value%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(key)%0A%09if%20(value%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20NaN%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20key.length%20%2B%20value.length%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * This will return the currently used size of a given Item,returns NaN if key is not found
 * @param key
 */
function getItemUsedSpace(key) {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value === null) {
        return NaN;
    }
    else {
        return key.length + value.length;
    }
}
```

Backup Assosiative Array, only [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%20%0A%20*%20Associative-array%20for%20localStorage%20holding%20key-%3Evalue%20%0A%20*%2F%0Ainterface%20LocalStorage_Backup%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0A%7D)

Get a Backup of localStorage - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20*%20This%20will%20return%20a%20backup%20assosiative-arry%20of%20localStorage%0A%20*%2F%0Afunction%20localStorage_getBackup()%3A%20LocalStorage_Backup%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20backup%3A%20LocalStorage_Backup%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20localStorage.length%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20key%20%3D%20localStorage.key(i)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20value%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(key)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20backup%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20backup%0A%7D%0A)

```
/**
 * This will return a localStorage-backup (Associative-Array key->value)
 */
function localStorage_getBackup() {
    var backup = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        backup[key] = value;
    }
    return backup;
}
```

Apply a Backup to localStorage - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%09*%20This%20will%20apply%20a%20localStorage-Backup%20(Associative-Array%20key-%3Evalue)%0A%09*%20%40param%20backup%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20associative-array%20%0A%09*%20%40param%20fClear%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20flag%20to%20clear%20all%20existing%20storage%20first.%20Default%3A%20true%0A%09*%20%40param%20fOverwriteExisting%20optional%20flag%20to%20replace%20existing%20keys.%20Default%3A%20true%0A%09*%2F%0Aexport%20function%20localStorage_applyBackup(backup%3A%20Backup%2C%20fClear%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%2C%20fOverwriteExisting%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true)%20%7B%0A%09if%20(fClear%20%3D%3D%20true)%20%7B%0A%09%09localStorage.clear()%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09for%20(let%20key%20in%20backup)%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(fOverwriteExisting%20%3D%3D%3D%20false%20%26%26%20backup%5Bkey%5D%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09continue%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09let%20value%20%3D%20backup%5Bkey%5D%0A%09%09localStorage.setItem(key%2C%20value)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * This will apply a localStorage-Backup (Associative-Array key->value)
 * @param backup            associative-array 
 * @param fClear             optional flag to clear all existing storage first.Default:true
 * @param fOverwriteExisting optional flag to replace existing keys. Default: true
 */
function localStorage_applyBackup(backup, fClear, fOverwriteExisting) {
    if (fClear === void 0) { fClear = true; }
    if (fOverwriteExisting === void 0) { fOverwriteExisting = true; }
    if (fClear == true) {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    for (var key in backup) {
        if (fOverwriteExisting === false && backup[key] !== undefined) {
            continue;
        }
        var value = backup[key];
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
}
```

Dump all information of localStorage in the console - [TypeScript-Version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F**%0A%20%20*%20This%20functions%20dumps%20all%20keys%20and%20values%20of%20the%20local%20Storage%20to%20the%20console%2C%0A%20%20*%20as%20well%20as%20the%20current%20size%20and%20number%20of%20items%0A%20%20*%20%40param%20fShowMaximumSize%20optional%2C%20flag%20show%20maximum%20size%20of%20localStorage.%20Default%3A%20false%0A%20%20*%2F%0Aexport%20function%20consoleInfo(fShowMaximumSize%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20false)%20%7B%0A%09let%20amount%20%3D%200%0A%09let%20size%20%3D%200%0A%0A%09for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20localStorage.length%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%0A%09%09var%20key%20%3D%20localStorage.key(i)%0A%09%09let%20value%20%3D%20localStorage.getItem(key)%3B%0A%09%09console.log(amount%2C%20key%2C%20value)%0A%09%09size%20%2B%3D%20key.length%20%2B%20value.length%0A%09%09amount%2B%2B%0A%09%7D%0A%09console.log(%22Total%20entries%3A%22%2C%20amount)%0A%09console.log(%22Total%20size%3A%22%2C%20size)%0A%09if%20(fShowMaximumSize%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20maxSize%20%3D%20getMaximumSpace()%0A%09%09console.log(%22Total%20size%3A%22%2C%20maxSize)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

```
/**
 * This functions dumps all keys and values of the local Storage to the console,
 * as well as the current size and number of items
 * @param fShowMaximumSize optional, flag show maximum size of localStorage. Default: false
 */
function localStorage_consoleInfo(fShowMaximumSize) {
    if (fShowMaximumSize === void 0) { fShowMaximumSize = false; }
    var amount = 0;
    var size = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i)
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        console.log(amount, key, value);
        size += key.length + value.length;
        amount++;
    }
    console.log("Total entries:", amount);
    console.log("Total size:", size);
    if (fShowMaximumSize === true) {
        var maxSize = localStorage_getMaximumSize();
        console.log("Total size:", maxSize);
    }
}
```

---

Notes

- Each key and value is using the exact amount of space equal to its string length
- The maximum storage-space allowed in my tests: ~5MB

  - 5000000 Edge
  - 5242880 Chrome
  - 5242880 Firefox
  - 5000000 IE
- *Firefox issue:* Don't use `for (var key in localStorage)` but: 
  `for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) { var key = localStorage.key(i)`. The `for..in`-loop it would give the `localStorage` Memberfunctions as `key`s

---

// Example - http://jsfiddle.net/1rqtd7pg/1/

```
console.log("LocalStorage supported:", LocalStorage.isSupported)
// true - I hope so anyways 
if(LocalStorage.isSupported) {
    localStorage.setItem("asd", "ASDASD")                           
    // sets / overwrites the item "asd"
    localStorage.setItem("asd" + Math.random(), "ASDASD")           
    // set another item each time you refresh the page
    var backup = LocalStorage.getBackup()                           
    // creates a backup, we will need it later!
    console.log(JSON.stringify(backup))                             
    // this is how the backup looks like
    var usedSpace = LocalStorage.getUsedSpace()                     
    // amount of space used right now
    console.log("Used Space:", usedSpace)
    var maxSpace = LocalStorage.getMaximumSpace()                   
    // amount of maximum space aviable
    console.log("Maximum Space:", maxSpace)
    var remSpace = LocalStorage.getRemainingSpace()                 
    // amount of remaining space
    console.log("Remaining Space:", remSpace)
    console.log("SpaceCheck", maxSpace === usedSpace + remSpace)    
    // true
    console.log("hasItem", LocalStorage.hasItem("nothis0ne"))       
    // we don't have this one in our localStorage
    localStorage.clear()                                            
    // oops, we deleted the localStorage!
    console.log("has asd", LocalStorage.hasItem("asd"))              
    // item asd is lost 
    LocalStorage.applyBackup(backup)                                
    // but we have a backup, restore it!
    LocalStorage.consoleInfo()                                      
    // show all the info we have, see the backup worked 
}
```

Comment: Is this an npm package? If not, can you make one and then write a post about it on dev.to?  I think you'll get a lot of contributors.

Comment: @Tamb I created my first npm package, let me know any feedback https://www.npmjs.com/package/localstorage-ext :)

Comment: The functions are great, but the naming is inconsistent with the example.  To use the example with the functions above, in the example rename LocalStorage. to localStorage_ then rename _getUsedSpace to _getUsedSize and _getMaximumSpace to _getMaximumSize